# How can I get the keys with the 'best' values from a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java

I have a problem:
My HashMap looks like:

```
[1,2,3,4] , 5
[1,3,3,4] , 2
[1,2,5,4] , -1
[1,2,4,4] , -1
```

I want to sort this hashmap and it worked! I get a `LinkedHashMap` back. What I want is to get the keys with the best 'values'. The best 'values' are the smalles number, in this example -1.
Is there a option to get in an `int[][]` the keys  `[1,2,5,4] and [1,2,4,4]` back ? For example if the best  value is 3 and it occurres 5 times, it should give me the 5 keys back. Equal for only one best value.
How could I do that?

```
 HashMap<int[], Double> hashMap = new HashMap<int[], Double>();
 value = sortHashMap(hashMap);

int[][] bestKey;
// bestkey = value.getTheKeysWithTheBestValue // how could I do that?  :(
// bestKey should be 
// [ [1,2,5,4], [1,2,4,4] ]

    private LinkedHashMap<int[], Double> sortHashMap(HashMap<int[], Double> hashMap) {
        List<Entry<int[], Double>> list = new ArrayList<>(hashMap.entrySet());
        list.sort(Entry.comparingByValue());
        return list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                (key1, key2) -> key2, LinkedHashMap::new));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

General idea:

- iterate over the list
- if the current value is "better", save the value as the "best" and store the key for this value in an ArrayList "best keys"
- if the current value is "worse", continue to the next
- if the current value is equal to the current "best" then append the key to the list of "best keys"

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work :( is there a chance you could create me the code for your solution?

Comment: @Kazim Did you have the same idea and implement it already? In that case post your attempt in your question. What did not work about that solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collections.min(yourMap.values())` to get the `min` value, stream over the entry set of your map and filter entries having the same value as the `min` value, map entries to keys and collect to array:

```
int[][] bestKeys = yourMap.entrySet()
                          .stream()
                          .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(Collections.min(myMap.values())))
                          .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                          .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Comment: Note that this computes the `Collections.min(myMap.values())` n times meaning that overall this is O(n^2), pre-computing the minimum once before is the way to go. But even then you iterate over the map twice instead of just once.

Comment: @luk2302 You are absolutely right. I just wanted to give a starting point and present the answer compactly enough. I leave the refactoring and improvement to the OP. Nevertheless, thank you for pointing it out.